# How do I check whether a variable is declared in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope, global-variables

How do I check whether a variable is declared, without using the `try`, `except` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dir()` command gives a list of all the variables in your global namespace. If your variable is `x_val`, use

```
'x_val' in dir()
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.